# How to retrieve stored array data in snappaydata?

Tags: sql, arrays, snappydata

I have sample array data in snappydata.

```
snappy-sql> select * from test;
ID         |DOMAINS                
-----------------------------------
1          |{"COL_0":[1,2]}        
2          |{"COL_0":[1,2,5,6,7,9]}
```

Inserted data using this query:

```
insert into test select 1, array(1,2);

insert into test select 2, array(1,2,5,6,7,9);
```

How to retrieve this stored array data? I tried this :

```
select * from test where DOMAINS having 1;

select * from test where DOMAINS = 1;

select * from test where DOMAINS IN 1;

select * from test where COL_0 HAVING 1;
```

Tried so many queries but these queries don't work for me.

Comment: Just looking at our documentation I found this:

You can also define complex types (Map, Array and StructType) as columns for column tables. To access the complex data from JDBC you can see [JDBCWithComplexTypes](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/snappydata/JDBCWithComplexTypes.scala) for examples. Perhaps the linked code can help

Answer (score 1):

If you are SQL from a remote client (i.e. JDBC or ODBC) you have to either flatten the projected result or use Serializer as shown in the example. But, if you can use the Spark API (Google search - working with complex data types in spark) you can navigate and access any of your nested structures in Spark SQL.

For remote SQL access(e.g. using the snappy shell) a simpler option would be too simply explode your result in the query like this ....

```
create table test using column as (select 1 as id, array(1,2) as nestedData from range(1))
insert into test select 2, array(1,2,3,4,5)
select id, explode(nesteddata) from test

+---+---+
| ID|col|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  1|  2|
|  2|  1|
|  2|  2|
|  2|  3|
|  2|  4|
|  2|  5|
+---+---+
```

Comment: how to query on col ?
"select id, explode(nesteddata) from test where col=1;"  I'm getting error

Comment: I need only that records where col has 1.

Comment: Try 'select * from (select id, explode(nesteddata) as col1 from test) t1 where col1 = 1'

Comment: how to dump csv data that contains (1,[1,3,45,6,8,79,])

Comment: How to dump this data throw java?